# Cl.exe /I include seemingly not working

Tags: visual-studio, cl

I am transpiling python files with cython to C++ using the embed option.
I then try to compile it using cl.exe:

```
cl .\Some_File.cpp /I 'C:\Program Files\Python\Python36\include'
```

which retruns the error:

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Python.h': No such file or directory

if I put python.h in the same directory, it moves on to the next include error. (also a file in the python include folder, expected behavior.)
But according tot he MS docs on cl /I is the correct parameter, so I'm stumped:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73f9s62w.aspx

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you get it working?

Comment: I believe cl .\Some_File.cpp /I "C:\Program Files\Python\Python36\include\\" worked

Answer (score 1):

**ANSWER**

Hey guys, so for all who is stuck with this problem , you can use:

`cl /I "<path>" filename.c`

**NOTES**

1. It seems the **double quotes are important** (I have tried a lot many times to compile without double quotes and it didn't work).
2. The path here can be absolute or relative.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, only " " are accepted as quotation marks:

```
cl .\Some_File.cpp /I "C:\Program Files\Python\Python36\include\\"
```