# how to pass fmt library for linking to cl.exe on windows 10

Tags: c++, vcpkg, fmt

I have this small piece of code in hello.cpp

```
#include "fmt/core.h"

int main()
{
    fmt::println("Hello from fnt!");
}
```

I am trying to compile this and I know that I am supposed to pass an additional linker option as it is not compiling.

`cl /EHsc /I C:\dev\vcpkg\packages\fmt_x64-windows\include hello.cpp`

and the output is

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.38.33126.1 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

hello.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.38.33126.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:hello.exe
hello.obj
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl fmt::v10::detail::vprint_mojibake(struct _iobuf *,class fmt::v10::basic_string_view<char>,class fmt::v10::basic_format_args<class fmt::v10::basic_format_context<class fmt::v10::appender,char> >)" (__imp_?vprint_mojibake@detail@v10@fmt@@YAXPAU_iobuf@@V?$basic_string_view@D@23@V?$basic_format_args@V?$basic_format_context@Vappender@v10@fmt@@D@v10@fmt@@@23@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl fmt::v10::print<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >(struct _iobuf *,class fmt::v10::basic_format_string<char,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > &&)" (??$print@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@v10@fmt@@YAXPAU_iobuf@@V?$basic_format_string@DV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@01@$$QAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl fmt::v10::vformat(class fmt::v10::basic_string_view<char>,class fmt::v10::basic_format_args<class fmt::v10::basic_format_context<class fmt::v10::appender,char> >)" (__imp_?vformat@v10@fmt@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$basic_string_view@D@12@V?$basic_format_args@V?$basic_format_context@Vappender@v10@fmt@@D@v10@fmt@@@12@@Z) referenced in function "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl fmt::v10::format<>(class fmt::v10::basic_format_string<char>)" (??$format@$$V@v10@fmt@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$basic_format_string@D$$V@01@@Z)
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl fmt::v10::vprint(struct _iobuf *,class fmt::v10::basic_string_view<char>,class fmt::v10::basic_format_args<class fmt::v10::basic_format_context<class fmt::v10::appender,char> >)" (__imp_?vprint@v10@fmt@@YAXPAU_iobuf@@V?$basic_string_view@D@12@V?$basic_format_args@V?$basic_format_context@Vappender@v10@fmt@@D@v10@fmt@@@12@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl fmt::v10::print<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >(struct _iobuf *,class fmt::v10::basic_format_string<char,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > &&)" (??$print@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@v10@fmt@@YAXPAU_iobuf@@V?$basic_format_string@DV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@01@$$QAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
hello.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

I installed fmt library using vcpkg and also performed the integrated installation.

Comment: Isn't it header online so no linking is required? In any case that is not a linker error you get. You should make sure that fmt is in your include paths and that all links are correct. Alternatively you can pass [include folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49912306/cl-exe-i-include-seemingly-not-working) via argument

Comment: @infinitezero sorry I updated my question. Sorry again.

Comment: can you figure out how to pass [linker options to cl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/link-pass-options-to-linker?view=msvc-170#example)? What happens if you try it.

Comment: `__declspec(dllimport)` in the error means it's looking for an import library (which should have a .lib extension but its not a static library) for a dll. At link time you will need to link to the .lib that implements fmt and at runtime have the .dll in a place your OS will search.

Comment: Looking at my `vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib` folder there is a `fmt.lib` file in it and `vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\bin` contains `fmt.dll`. This is the .lib and .dll file you will need. When I used fmt with vcpkg I had CMake do it for me so I did not need mess with the compiler or linker settings.

Comment: adding `/DFMT_HEADER_ONLY`  helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This heled me

`cl /EHsc /I C:\dev\vcpkg\packages\fmt_x64-windows\include /DFMT_HEADER_ONLY  hello.cpp`